# Are these two arguments logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I have two compound propositions:

1. $(A \land B)$
2. $\neg (A \rightarrow \neg B)$

I know they are equivalent, because I made their truth tables, however I'm still running into a problem when I use logical equivalences.

I tried applying the Implication Law to number 2 and obtained:
$\neg ((\neg A) \lor (B))$
Then I applied De Morgans law and obtained:
$(A \land (\neg B))$

Clearly those two compound proposition are not equivalent. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `obtained: not((not A) or (B))` Check this step more carefully. You should actually obtain $\lnot(\lnot A \lor \lnot B)\,$.

Comment: Thank you, I found my mistake!